# canvas.getContext('2D') returns null value

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I created a canvas and called its `getContext()` method. But it returns `null` for the context.

Here is the code that I used:

```
<script>
    window.onload =  init;
    function init(){
        var canvas, context;
        canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
        context = canvas.getContext('2D');
        console.log(canvas);
        console.log(context);
    }
</script>
```

I got this in my console:

```
<canvas id="canvas" width='500' height='250'>This is a canvas</canvas> null
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I think it's `2d` with a lowercase "d". Try it this way:

```
context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

And if it's not that, then according [to the specs](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/the-canvas-element.html#dom-canvas-getcontext):

> (`getContext`) Returns null if the given context ID is not supported, if the canvas has already been initialized with the other context type (e.g. trying to get a "2d" context after getting a "webgl" context).